# What game engine/framework i could use to work with air mobile without fps problems?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, air, starling-framework

I hear that most of flash engines have problems on mobile devices except Starling Framework . But starling didn't feed all my needs as pathfinding and tilemaps tool that i can perfectly use with flixel. What engine/framework i could use with Air or starling framework without miss much fps? I need collisions, pathfinding and tilemaps support.

Answer (score 1):

As of this date (May 22, 2012) you will have to wait for that. There is not a single engine that rolls all of the above into one easy-to-use package like Flixel. The team working on Flixel has anncounced the intent to make such a thing (http://www.photonstorm.com/archives/2524/looking-for-developers-to-help-build-a-new-game-framework) But to date it does not exist.

That said, you could build a game using Box2D and some implementation of pathfindting (like a*) and just use starling to render the game. You'll sink some time in setup, but its not impossible. Before stage 3D i did a similar approach for this game:

http://www.candystand.com/play/cougar-town

It uses box2D to manipulate graphics.

(minus the pathfindong of course)

I released the source code of a similar game on my blog here:
It uses the old display list. But you could see how it works and switch it to startling. 
http://plasticsturgeon.com/2011/05/box-2d-2-1a-cannon-game-part-3-the-complete-game-source/